# mkdir php TCPDF ERROR

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

Tenho uma aplicação que gera um arquivo pdf e salva em um diretório especifico.
Segui os passos do manual php(http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) para uso dessa função.

Já dei permissão como sudo(roda em um server ubuntu com nginx)mas continuo recebendo o mesmo retorno de erro.TCPDF ERROR: Unable to create output file
Esse erro é gerado porque depois de criar e salvar, o arquivo deve ser baixado,mas como o arquivo não esta sendo gerado tenho esse erro de retorno.

Linha:

```
$html2pdf->Output('./modelos/docs/'.'.pdf', 'F');
$modelObj->add_file($dados['id'], './modelos/docs/'.'.pdf', "Regulamento");
$html2pdf->Output('regulamento_'.$dados['id'].'.pdf', 'D');
```

Comment: Usuário e grupo da pasta de storage é www-data:www-data?

Comment: tu quer saber se o usuario foi definido como dono dessa pasta ?

Comment: se foi essa a pergunta.Sim,foi.